# showing the selected li when dropdown is opened jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a very customized requirement for design so i have to create a custom select rather than using the conventional one.

i have designed the select and integrated pretty much every feature there is only one last scenario i am facing as we know when we select an option from regular select it closes and whenever we reopen the select it always focuses the selected item, even if you scroll  up down after reopening the select it will always focus on the selected item.

i have made the similar scenario when my custom select is clicked the list opens and when i click on some of the child it gets highlighted and closed, now if i reopen the select in my case it focuses on the current select item by default maybe that is because that was the last clicked item and there was not operation after that but here comes the problem if move my scroll up and down and close the custom select and then reopen it it doesn't focuses on the highlighted item anymore, because maybe the last operation was the scroll so when it got closed it stopped at that point and started from there on click.

**Summary**

i want to search for the selected item in the list and focus it so that whenever the dropdown opens it takes the viewport to the selected item, here's code.

```js
    // select snippet
    
            $(".select-options").html("");
    
            $(".select").on("click", function () {
    
                //this is the part where i need to take the viewport to the selected item
                $(this).find("li.selected").focus();
                //this is the part where i need to take the viewport to the selected item
                
                $(".select").not($(this)).removeClass("focus");
                $(".select").not($(this)).removeClass("overflow-auto");
                $(this).toggleClass("overflow-auto");
                if ($(this).hasClass("focus")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("focus");
                } else
                {
                    $(this).addClass("focus");
                }
                $(".select .select-options").not($(this).children(".select-options")).removeClass("active");
                $(".select").not($(this)).removeClass("border-bottom-zero");
    
                if ($(this).hasClass("border-bottom-zero"))
                {
                    $(this).removeClass("border-bottom-zero");
                } else
                {
                    $(this).addClass("border-bottom-zero");
                }
                if ($(this).children(".select-options").hasClass("active")) {
                    $(this).children(".select-options").removeClass("active");
                } else
                {
                    $(this).children(".select-options").addClass("active");
                }
            });
            $(".select select > option").each(function () {
                $(this).parents(".select").find(".select-options").append("<li class='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</li>");
            });
    
            $(".select-options li").click(function () {
                $(this).parents(".select-options").children("li").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $(this).parents(".select").find("h5").text($(this).text());
                $(this).parents(".select").find("select").val($(this).attr("class"));
            });
    
            $(".select-mileage .icons").on("click", function () {
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass("border-left-bottom-zero"))
                {
                    $(this).parent().removeClass("border-left-bottom-zero");
                } else
                {
                    $(this).parent().addClass("border-left-bottom-zero");
                }
                $(this).parent().find(".mileage-select-options").toggleClass("active");
            });
            $(".select-mileage li").click(function () {
                $(this).parents(".select-mileage").find("h6").text($(this).text())
                $("#km-or-mi").val($(this).text());
                $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
                $(this).parents(".fields").removeClass("border-left-bottom-zero");
            });
            $(".fields").focusout(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("focus");
            });
            // select snippet
```

```css
    .select{
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .select::before{
        content: url("../images/caret-down.png");
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 17px;
    }
    .select select{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .select .select-options{
        position: absolute;
        top: 101%;
        background-color: white;
        width: calc(100% - 63px);
        z-index: 1;
        left: 64px;
        border: 1px solid #dcdee3;
        border-top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .select .active{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .select .active .selected{
        background-color: #dcdee3;
    }
    .select .select-options li{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdee3;*/
        color: #484848;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight:400;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 28px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .select .select-options li::before{
        position: absolute;
        left: 28px;
        bottom: 0;
        content: "";
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #dcdee3;
        width: calc(100% - 63px);
    }
    .fields{
        border: 1px solid #dcdee3;
        width: 85%;
        margin-right: 98px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 9px;
        vertical-align: top;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(251, 251, 252, 0.75);
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out , border 0.3s ease-in-out;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .overflow-auto{
        overflow: initial;
    }
    .fields img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
        left: 50%;
    }
    .fields .icons{
        border-right: 1px solid #dcdee3;
        height: 100%;
        width: 65px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .fields input , .fields h5{
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-left: 26px;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #687182;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 76%;
        margin-top: 22px;
    }
    .focus{
        border-color: #53a6fa;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px .2rem rgba(83,166,250,.25);
        transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out , border 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    input:focus{
        outline-width: 0;
    }
    .fields span{
        position: absolute;
        left: 86px;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #e35959;
        top: 24px;
    }
    .fields input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #687182;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .fields input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #687182;
        opacity:  1;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .fields input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #687182;
        opacity:  1;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .fields input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #687182;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .fields input , .fields h5{
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-left: 26px;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #687182;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 76%;
        margin-top: 22px;
    }
    .select .select-options {
        top: 102%;
        max-height: 250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    position: absolute;
    top: 101%;
    background-color: white;
    width: calc(100% - 63px);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 64px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdee3;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-color: rgb(220, 222, 227);
    border-top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="fields select" id="category">
    <div class="icons">
    <img src="http://localhost/dealercarpages_laravel/public/assets-dealer/images/car.png">
    </div>
    <h5>Enter Category</h5>
    <span>*</span>
    
    <div class="select-options">
     <li class="9">Convertible</li>
     <li class="10">Coupe</li>
     <li class="11">Hatchback</li>
     <li class="12">Sedan</li>
     <li class="13">Wagon</li>
     <li class="14">Minivan / Van</li>
     <li class="15">SUV / Crossover</li>
     <li class="16">Truck / Pickup</li>
     <li class="17">Commercial / Cargo / Bus</li>
     <li class="18">Motorcycle / Scooter</li>
     <li class="19">Wheelchair Accessible</li>
     <li class="20">Atv</li><li class="21">Boat</li>
     <li class="22">RV</li><li class="23">Snowmobile</li>
     <li class="24">Trailer</li><li class="25">Types</li>
     <li class="26">Was</li></div>
    <p class="error" style="display: none;">This Value is Required</p>
    
     <select name="category">
      <option value="9">Convertible</option>
      <option value="10" selected="">Coupe</option>
      <option value="11">Hatchback</option>
      <option value="12">Sedan</option>
      <option value="13">Wagon</option>
      <option value="14">Minivan / Van</option>
      <option value="15">SUV / Crossover</option>
      <option value="16">Truck / Pickup</option>
      <option value="17">Commercial / Cargo / Bus</option>
      <option value="18">Motorcycle / Scooter</option>
      <option value="19">Wheelchair Accessible</option>
      <option value="20">Atv</option>
      <option value="21">Boat</option>
      <option value="22">RV</option>
      <option value="23">Snowmobile</option>
      <option value="24">Trailer</option>
      <option value="25">Types</option>
      <option value="26">Was</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jL9ypmuo/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can calculate the height of the `li`s that didn't be selected and `scrollTop()` to the height.

```js
// select snippet

$(".select-options").html("");

$(".select").on("click", function() {

  //this is the part where i need to take the viewport to the selected item
  let $li = $(this).find("li.selected")
  let index = $li.index() // find the index of the selected li
  let height = $li.outerHeight() // get outerHeight of `li`
  if($li.length>0)
    $(this).find('.select-options').scrollTop(index * height)
  //this is the part where i need to take the viewport to the selected item

  $(".select").not($(this)).removeClass("focus");
  $(".select").not($(this)).removeClass("overflow-auto");
  $(this).toggleClass("overflow-auto");
  if ($(this).hasClass("focus")) {
    $(this).removeClass("focus");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  }
  $(".select .select-options").not($(this).children(".select-options")).removeClass("active");
  $(".select").not($(this)).removeClass("border-bottom-zero");

  if ($(this).hasClass("border-bottom-zero")) {
    $(this).removeClass("border-bottom-zero");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("border-bottom-zero");
  }
  if ($(this).children(".select-options").hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).children(".select-options").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(this).children(".select-options").addClass("active");
  }
});
$(".select select > option").each(function() {
  $(this).parents(".select").find(".select-options").append("<li class='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</li>");
});

$(".select-options li").click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".select-options").children("li").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $(this).parents(".select").find("h5").text($(this).text());
  $(this).parents(".select").find("select").val($(this).attr("class"));
});

$(".select-mileage .icons").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("border-left-bottom-zero")) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("border-left-bottom-zero");
  } else {
    $(this).parent().addClass("border-left-bottom-zero");
  }
  $(this).parent().find(".mileage-select-options").toggleClass("active");
});
$(".select-mileage li").click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".select-mileage").find("h6").text($(this).text())
  $("#km-or-mi").val($(this).text());
  $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
  $(this).parents(".fields").removeClass("border-left-bottom-zero");
});
$(".fields").focusout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("focus");
});
// select snippet
```

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.select::before {
  content: url("../images/caret-down.png");
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
}

.select select {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.select .select-options {
  position: absolute;
  top: 101%;
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 63px);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 64px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdee3;
  border-top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.select .active {
  visibility: visible;
}

.select .active .selected {
  background-color: #dcdee3;
}

.select .select-options li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdee3;*/
  color: #484848;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 28px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.select .select-options li::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 28px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #dcdee3;
  width: calc(100% - 63px);
}

.fields {
  border: 1px solid #dcdee3;
  width: 85%;
  margin-right: 98px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(251, 251, 252, 0.75);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out, border 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-auto {
  overflow: initial;
}

.fields img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.fields .icons {
  border-right: 1px solid #dcdee3;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.fields input,
.fields h5 {
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 26px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #687182;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 76%;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.focus {
  border-color: #53a6fa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px .2rem rgba(83, 166, 250, .25);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out, border 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}

.fields span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 86px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #e35959;
  top: 24px;
}

.fields input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #687182;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fields input:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #687182;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fields input::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #687182;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fields input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #687182;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fields input,
.fields h5 {
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 26px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #687182;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 76%;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.select .select-options {
  top: 102%;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

position: absolute;
top: 101%;
background-color: white;
width: calc(100% - 63px);
z-index: 1;
left: 64px;
border: 1px solid #dcdee3;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: rgb(220,
222,
227);
border-top: 0;
visibility: hidden;
padding: 10px 0;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="fields select" id="category">
  <div class="icons">
    <img src="http://localhost/dealercarpages_laravel/public/assets-dealer/images/car.png">
  </div>
  <h5>Enter Category</h5>
  <span>*</span>

  <div class="select-options">
    <li class="9">Convertible</li>
    <li class="10">Coupe</li>
    <li class="11">Hatchback</li>
    <li class="12">Sedan</li>
    <li class="13">Wagon</li>
    <li class="14">Minivan / Van</li>
    <li class="15">SUV / Crossover</li>
    <li class="16">Truck / Pickup</li>
    <li class="17">Commercial / Cargo / Bus</li>
    <li class="18">Motorcycle / Scooter</li>
    <li class="19">Wheelchair Accessible</li>
    <li class="20">Atv</li>
    <li class="21">Boat</li>
    <li class="22">RV</li>
    <li class="23">Snowmobile</li>
    <li class="24">Trailer</li>
    <li class="25">Types</li>
    <li class="26">Was</li>
  </div>
  <p class="error" style="display: none;">This Value is Required</p>

  <select name="category">
    <option value="9">Convertible</option>
    <option value="10" selected="">Coupe</option>
    <option value="11">Hatchback</option>
    <option value="12">Sedan</option>
    <option value="13">Wagon</option>
    <option value="14">Minivan / Van</option>
    <option value="15">SUV / Crossover</option>
    <option value="16">Truck / Pickup</option>
    <option value="17">Commercial / Cargo / Bus</option>
    <option value="18">Motorcycle / Scooter</option>
    <option value="19">Wheelchair Accessible</option>
    <option value="20">Atv</option>
    <option value="21">Boat</option>
    <option value="22">RV</option>
    <option value="23">Snowmobile</option>
    <option value="24">Trailer</option>
    <option value="25">Types</option>
    <option value="26">Was</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou so much you saved my day, i though it to be some difficult scenario didnt knew it was that simple, keep up the good work!